# Limit relationship's primary join to one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model representing a Delivery; the delivery has a destination, a parcel id, and a date:

```
class Delivery(Base):
    delivery_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    parcel_id = Column(ForeignKey('parcels.parcel_id'))
    scheduled_date = Column(DateTime)
    destination_id = Column(ForeignKey('location.location_id'))
```

Now, the *origin* of the delivery is equal to the destination of the prior delivery for the same parcel. Rather than denormalizing that information by maintaining a pointer-based linked list, I'm using the scheduled date to order deliveries, currently like this:

```
def origin(delivery):
    prior = session.query(Delivery)
           .filter(
                Delivery.parcel_id == delivery.parcel_id,
                Delivery.scheduled_date < delivery.scheduled_date,
           )
           .order_by(Delivery.scheduled_date.desc())
           .first()
    return prior.location_id if prior else None
```

In pure SQL, I can turn this separate query into a simple subquery + join that I include when I load a delivery. I've gotten far enough that I can load *all* the related deliveries that happened prior to the current delivery:

```
_prior_delivery = \
    select([Delivery.parcel_id, Delivery.scheduled_date, Location]) \
        .where(and_(Location.location_id == remote(Delivery.location_id)) \
        .order_by(Delivery.scheduled_date.desc()) \
        .alias("prior_delivery")

Delivery.origin = relationship(
    Location,
    primaryjoin=and_(_prior_delivery.c.parcel_id == foreign(Delivery.parcel_id),
                     _prior_delivery.c.scheduled_date < foreign(Delivery.scheduled_date)),
    secondary=_prior_delivery,
    secondaryjoin=_prior_delivery.c.location_id == foreign(Location.location_id),
    uselist=False,
    viewonly=True)
```

Because of the `uselist=False`, this actually works; but under the hood it's returning every single delivery that occured prior to the current one; SQLAlchemy prints a warning and the resultset is massively larger than it needs to be.

My question: How do I apply a `limit(1)` to this read-only relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## First attempt

The reason this is difficult is that relationships need to be able to be joined into the main query. SQLAlchemy needs to be able to load the relationship *in the same query* in order to implement eager loading. The question becomes, how do you write a *single* query that loads a list of `Delivery`s and each of their `origin`s?

```
SELECT delivery.*, location.* FROM delivery
LEFT JOIN location ON location.location_id = (
  SELECT destination_id FROM delivery prior
  WHERE delivery.parcel_id = prior.parcel_id
  ORDER BY prior.scheduled_date DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Effectively, the correlated subquery

```
SELECT destination_id FROM delivery prior
WHERE delivery.parcel_id = prior.parcel_id
ORDER BY prior.scheduled_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

becomes a computed foreign key `origin_id` on which you can join to the `location` table. Translating that into SQLAlchemy, it would be something like:

```
delivery = Delivery.__table__
location = Location.__table__
prior = alias(delivery, "prior")
_origin_id = select([prior.c.destination_id])\
    .where(delivery.c.parcel_id == prior.c.parcel_id)\
    .order_by(prior.c.scheduled_date.desc())\
    .limit(1)
Delivery.origin = relationship(
    Location,
    primaryjoin=_origin_id == location.c.location_id,
    viewonly=True)
```

Unfortunately, **this doesn't seem to work**, for all the combinations of `remote` and `foreign` annotations I've tried.

## Using a `SELECT` with a correlated subquery as `secondary`

A next-best solution would be to use a fake secondary table:

```
SELECT delivery.*, location.* FROM delivery
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT delivery.delivery_id, (
    SELECT destination_id FROM delivery prior
    WHERE delivery.parcel_id = prior.parcel_id
    ORDER BY prior.scheduled_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS origin_id FROM delivery
) delivery_origin ON delivery.delivery_id = delivery_origin.delivery_id
LEFT JOIN location ON delivery_origin.origin_id = location.location_id;
```

In SQLAlchemy, this is:

```
delivery = Delivery.__table__
location = Location.__table__
current = alias(delivery, "current")
prior = alias(delivery, "prior")
_origin_id = select([prior.c.destination_id])\
    .where(current.c.parcel_id == prior.c.parcel_id)\
    .order_by(prior.c.scheduled_date.desc())\
    .limit(1)\
    .label("origin_id")
delivery_origin = select([
    UnaryExpression(current.c.delivery_id, operator=custom_op("")).label("delivery_id"),
    _origin_id,
]).select_from(current)
Delivery.origin = relationship(
    Location,
    primaryjoin=delivery.c.delivery_id == foreign(delivery_origin.c.delivery_id),
    secondaryjoin=foreign(delivery_origin.c.origin_id) == location.c.location_id,
    secondary=delivery_origin,
    viewonly=True,
    uselist=False)
```

Unfortunately, there appears to be a bug (possibly related to [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3458)) that makes SQLAlchemy emit an incorrect join, so we need to apply a small hack:

```
delivery = Delivery.__table__
location = Location.__table__
current = alias(delivery, "current")
prior = alias(delivery, "prior")

# HACK: wrap delivery_id in an empty unary operator
_delivery_id = UnaryExpression(current.c.delivery_id, operator=custom_op(""))\
    .label("delivery_id")
# /HACK

_origin_id = select([prior.c.destination_id])\
    .where(current.c.parcel_id == prior.c.parcel_id)\
    .order_by(prior.c.scheduled_date.desc())\
    .limit(1)\
    .label("origin_id")
delivery_origin = select([
    _delivery_id,
    _origin_id,
]).select_from(current)
Delivery.origin = relationship(
    Location,
    primaryjoin=delivery.c.delivery_id == foreign(delivery_origin.c.delivery_id),
    secondaryjoin=foreign(delivery_origin.c.origin_id) == location.c.location_id,
    secondary=delivery_origin,
    viewonly=True,
    uselist=False)
```

## Using a `SELECT` with window functions as `secondary`

An alternative implementation that may have better performance characteristics would be using window functions:

```
SELECT delivery.*, location.* FROM delivery
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    delivery.delivery_id,
    lag(delivery.delivery_id) OVER (PARTITION BY delivery.parcel_id ORDER BY delivery.scheduled_date) AS origin_id
  FROM delivery
) delivery_origin ON delivery.delivery_id = delivery_origin.delivery_id
LEFT JOIN location ON delivery_origin.origin_id = location.location_id;
```

As before, we need to apply a similar hack to get SQLAlchemy to produce the correct SQL:

```
delivery = Delivery.__table__
location = Location.__table__
current = alias(delivery, "current")
prior = alias(delivery, "prior")

# HACK: wrap delivery_id in an empty unary operator
_delivery_id = UnaryExpression(current.c.delivery_id, operator=custom_op(""))\
    .label("delivery_id")
# /HACK

_origin_id = func.lag(current.c.delivery_id)\
    .over(partition_by=current.c.parcel_id,
          order_by=current.c.scheduled_date)\
    .label("origin_id")
delivery_origin = select([
    _delivery_id,
    _origin_id,
]).select_from(current)
Delivery.origin = relationship(
    Location,
    primaryjoin=delivery.c.delivery_id == foreign(delivery_origin.c.delivery_id),
    secondaryjoin=foreign(delivery_origin.c.origin_id) == location.c.location_id,
    secondary=delivery_origin,
    viewonly=True,
    uselist=False)
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer, thank you so much for lending a hand; works like a charm!